# How do I print a dictionary vs a defaultdict based dictionary as a yaml file using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

Please refer to this trivial block of code shown below.  My goal is to use defaultdict to come up with a relatively simple dictionary, and further print the results out as a yaml file.

When I manually define the dictionary, it seems to work just fine and the YAML is displayed exactly the way I want it, but when I use `defaultdict` to come up with a dictionary, I get an error message and unfortunately I am not able to decipher that.

When I print the dictionary as a JSON, it prints the exact same output.   What I am missing?

```
import sys,ruamel.yaml
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def dict_maker():
    return defaultdict(dict_maker)

S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
app = "someapp"

d = {'beats':{'name':S(app), 'udp_address':S('239.1.1.1:10101')}}

foo = dict_maker()
foo["beats"]["name"] = S(app)
foo["beats"]["udp_address"] = S("239.1.1.1:10101")

print "Regular dictionary"
print json.dumps(d, indent=4)

print "defaultdict dictionary"
print json.dumps(foo, indent=4)

print "dictionary as a yaml\n"
ruamel.yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)

print "defaultdict dictionary as a yaml\n"
ruamel.yaml.dump(foo, sys.stdout, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

**Error Message**

```
raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object: %s" % data)
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: defaultdict(<function dict_maker at 0x7f1253725a28>, {'beats': defaultdict(<function dict_maker at 0x7f1253725a28>, {'name': u'someapp', 'udp_address': u'239.1.1.1:10101'})})
```

Comment: You should start using the `print` function, even if you are still using Python 2. You should also always include an interrogative sentence in a post here on [so], i.e. a sentence with ending with a question mark. (Your sentence "My question is .." was not followed by an actual question)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the word "dictionary" when refering to a Python `dict`. There is however no such thing as a "defaultdict based dictionary", that would imply that `foo` after

```
foo = dict_maker()
```

would be a `dict`, and of course it is not: `foo` is a `defaultdict` which is `dict` based (i.e. exactly the other way around from what you write).

That JSON dumps this, is not surprising, as it cannot do more than stupidly dump the key-value pairs as if it were a `dict`. But when you try to load that JSON back, you see how useless this is as, you cannot continue working with it (at least not in the way expected):

```
import sys
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import io

def dict_maker():
    return defaultdict(dict_maker)

app = "someapp"

foo = dict_maker()
foo["beats"]["name"] = app
foo["beats"]["udp_address"] = "239.1.1.1:10101"
io = io.StringIO()
json.dump(foo, io, indent=4)
io.seek(0)
bar = json.load(io)
bar['otherapp']['name'] = 'some_alt_app'
print(bar['beats']['udp_address'])
```

The above throws: `KeyError: 'otherapp'`. And that is because JSON doesn't keep all the information needed.

However, if you use the unsafe YAML dumper, then `ruamel.yaml` can dump and load this fine:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from collections import defaultdict
import io

def dict_maker():
    return defaultdict(dict_maker)

app = "someapp"

yaml = YAML(typ='unsafe')
foo = dict_maker()
foo["beats"]["name"] = app
foo["beats"]["udp_address"] = "239.1.1.1:10101"
io = io.StringIO()
yaml.dump(foo, io)
io.seek(0)
print(io.getvalue())
bar = yaml.load(io)
bar['otherapp']['name'] = 'some_alt_app'
print(bar['beats']['udp_address'])
```

this doesn't throw an error, as `bar` is again a `defaultdict` with `dict_maker` as the function it defaults to. The above prints

```
239.1.1.1:10101
```

as you would expect.

That the `RoundTripDumper/Loader` doesn't support this out-of-the-box, is because it is based on the `SafeDumper/Loader`, which cannot dump/load arbitrary Python instances like `defaultdict` and its `dict_maker` function reference. Enabling that would make the loading unsafe.

So if you need to use the `RoundTripDumper` you should add a representer for `defaultdict` or a subclass thereof (and possible one for `dict_maker` as well). To be able to load that, you need constructor(s) as well. How to do that is described in the documentation ([Dumping Python classes](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html))